# Atribuição do radio button através da div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estou precisando fazer um questionário de perguntas simples e respostas de multipla escolha, neste caso escolhi o radio button...

No meu PHP estou recebendo os posts e já estou fazendo as verificação das respostas com `if`. O meu problema é, no layout não existe aquela bolinha do radio button... ele simplesmente pega através do `for` mas não sei o que esta acontecendo que não esta funcionando.

Até o momento ele está desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E é para estar desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E meu código é este:

-HTML

```
<div class="block_question1">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="pg1_q1">
                                <input name="acerto1" value="acerto1" type="radio" class="selecionar">
                                <label for="acerto1">Red</label>
                            </li>

                            <li id="pg1_q2">
                                <input name="acerto12" type="radio">
                                <label for="">yellow</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="pg1_q3">
                                <input name="acerto1" type="radio">
                                <label for="">Blue</label>
                            </li>

                            <li id="pg1_q4">
                                <input name="acerto1" type="radio">
                                <label for="">Green</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

-JS

```
  $('#perguntas-1 #pg1_q1').click(function () {
        $('.block_question1 #pg1_q1').toggleClass('active_answers');
        $("#pg1_q1 .selecionar").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});
```

Em resumo, quero que clique na div do buttao e o value seja inserido para que o php reconheça o post

**obs**: Seu eu clico no radio button ele funciona... se eu clico na div que forma o botao ele não aplica o **value**

Comment: Você que seja atribuído um valor ao `input:radio` ao clicar na `div` ou no elemento `li`? Por que você já não atribui o valor ao `input`?

Comment: Não deu para entender direito o que vc quer. É para clocar na `li` ou na `div`? E depois de clocar vc quer que o `Radio` fique como o atributo `Checked` é isso?

Comment: É que precisava esconder a **bolinha** do radio, e ao clicar na div ele insere o value.... quando eu escondo com `visibility:hidden` o value para de funcionar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `label` define um rótulo para um elemento `input`, dessa forma melhora a usabilidade do usuário, que não precisa clicar examente no `input`. Para isso, é necessário associar o `for` da `label` com o mesmo valor do `id` do `input`.

No seu caso, o ideal seria colocar o `input` dentro da `label` e customizar o layout diretamente nela.

Veja no exemplo abaixo.

```css
label {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  background: #e5d86e;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="red"><input type="radio" id="red" value="red" name="color">Red</label>
  <label for="yellow"><input type="radio" id="yellow" value="yellow" name="color">yellow</label>
  <label for="blue"><input type="radio" id="blue" value="blue" name="color">Blue</label>
  <label for="green"><input type="radio" id="green" value="green" name="color">Green</label>
</form>
```

Comment: mas ai se eu coloco o visibility: hidden; ele para de funcionar, nao e?

Comment: Funciona sim, mas daí você verifica o valor do checked do input, se é true ou false.

Comment: Mas por que ele só aparece true e false? Tem alguma maneira de escapar disso?

Comment: Depende da sua necessidade. Se precisa pegar o valor daquele elemento utilize o atributo `value`. Se precisa saber se o elemento está checkado utilize o `checked`.